# redirect the page if a user login was empty at wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect

I have no problem to redirect the page if a user enter the wrong username or password with the following code. However, if a user left either the username or password empty, the redirect function fail, it will go to wordpress/login.php. I want to redirect the page if the user didn't enter anything but hit the submit button.

```html
<?php
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'my_front_end_login_fail' );  // hook failed login

function my_front_end_login_fail( $username ) {
   $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // where did the post submission come from?
   // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
   if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {
      wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );  // let's append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
      exit;
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: If I remember the names correctly, it would be something like this, checking the post values etc.  `if ( $_POST['log'] === "" && $_POST['pwd'] === "" ) do stuff`

Comment: I have tried that already,if I put the wp_redirect inside this if statement, it give me an error like header already sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'wp_authenticate' action, this is one of the earliest action in the login process:

```
add_action( 'wp_authenticate', '_catch_empty_user', 1, 2 );

function _catch_empty_user( $username, $pwd ) {
 if ( empty( $username ) ) {
   wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to_whereever_you_want );
   exit();
 }
}
```

Comment: It works. but, it cause another problem, when I tried to go to www.mysite.com/wp-login.php, it redirect no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I extended on the version of alex so it doesn't crash in the wp-admin login page.

```
    add_action( 'wp_authenticate', '_catch_empty_user', 1, 2 );
    
    /**
     * Catches an error attempt that is missing either email / password then redirects back to the page it came from. Will ignore wp-login / wp-admin login attempts, those are handled the wordpress default way.
     *
     * @param $username mixed
     * @param $pwd mixed
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function _catch_empty_user( $username, $pwd ) {
        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?? false;  // where did the post submission come from?

        if ( $referrer === false ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( empty( $username ) || empty( $pwd ) ) {
            if ( ! empty( $referrer ) && ! strstr( $referrer, 'wp-login' ) && ! strstr( $referrer, 'wp-admin' ) ) {
                $url = add_query_arg( 'login', 'failed', $referrer );
                wp_safe_redirect( $url );  // let's append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
```